# Turn Object Into Array Without Changing Its Identity

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, the `useRef` function returns an object with the argument stored under the key `current`.  Sometimes I'd like to use an array, e.g. to keep a list of references, like

```
const divsRef = useRef([]);
return Array.from({ length: n }, (_, i) => (
  <div
    ref={function (el) {
      divsRef.current[i] = el;
    }}
  />
));
```

but typing out `current` all the time is cumbersome.  If I do

```
const divsRef = useRef();
return Array.from({ length: n }, (_, i) => (
  <div
    ref={function (el) {
      divsRef[i] = el;
    }}
  />
));
```

instead, then the resulting object isn't iterable.  Hence my question, is there an easy way to turn an object into an iterable array, *without* changing its identity (otherwise the object wouldn't persist between rerenders)?  I got it iterable by doing `Object.setPrototypeOf(divsRef, Object.getPrototypeOf([]))` but then `[...divsRef]` always returns the empty array.

Comment: "but typing out `current` all the time is cumbersome": Welcome to programming. You'll get used to it.

Comment: I don't get it: why is it "cumbersome" to type out current? It's like saying it's cumbersome to use `Array.from()` and you just want `Array()`

Comment: People on IRC told me that `Array()` is bad, so IDK.  But I'm not talking about typing it out in the snippet I posted here, I meant typing it out whenever I want to access the ref.  All that `useRef` is doing, basically, is to create an object and returning it back in each rerender.  It should be agnostic about the shape of the object (it actually is, it just creates the `current` property on its first  call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t need the actual ref for anything other than to access and use the array at its `.current` property, then you can use this syntax to avoid the repeated typing of that property name:

```js
const {current: divArray} = useRef([]);
// divArray.push(div);
// etc…
```

And if you do, then just destructure it on a separate line:

```js
const divsRef = useRef([]);
const {current: divArray} = divsRef;
```